# Undefined variable inside textbox

Tags: php

I'm having errors like this in 4 of the text boxes.
`<b/><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: fname in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webpage\phpmyadmin\db\form.php</b> on line <b>..</b><br />`
I read about similar problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766611/undefined-variable) but it didn't work for me.
 Where did I make mistake?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])&& isset($_POST['fname'])
&& isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$passhash = md5($pass);
}
?>

<form action="#" method="POST">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
Firstname:<br>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">  <br>
Lastname:<br>
<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname ?>"> <br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check isset and then echo because before posting data you will not get all data:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($name)) echo $name; ?>"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
Firstname:<br>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php if(isset($fname)) echo $fname; ?>">  <br>
Lastname:<br>
<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php if(isset($lname)) echo $lname; ?>"> <br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php if(isset($name )) echo $name; ?>` instead `<?php echo $name ?>` and same for all ..

OR

you can use `$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name']: "";` instead `$name = $_POST['name'];` and same for all ..

Answer (score 0):

Initialize  `$name = $pass  = $fname  = $lname  = $email  = $passhash  ='';`

Before this line `'if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])&& isset($_POST['fname'])' ;`

Your code will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

i got your problem you are trying to access variable which is not decalre. you can try below code its working fine.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])&& isset($_POST['fname'])
&& isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$passhash = md5($pass);
}
?>

<form action="#" method="POST">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($name)?$name:"" ?>"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
Firstname:<br>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo isset($fname)?$fname : "" ?>">  <br>
Lastname:<br>
<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo isset($lname)?$lname:"" ?>"> <br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo  isset($email) ? $email : "" ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here i am checked with isset function if variable is set then print value otherwise blank.